# MySQL Previous week

Tags: php, mysql

I want to retrieve data from last week and 15 weeks back.

**Note:** Only the same weekday 15 weeks back, not all data inbetween. For example, I want data every Thursday 15 weeks back.

This is a simplification of my MySQL table with desired result.

```
Station | Type |     Date    |   Value
5          2     2012-08-02     3
5          2     2012-07-26     5
5          2     2012-07-19     1
```

The way I do it today is via PHP:

```
$dates = "(";
for($j=1; $j<=15; $j++) { // 15 weeks back, same weekday
$dates .= "'" . date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-{$j} week")) . "', ";
 }
```

Then i append this to a MySQL query using " SELECT * FROM `blabla` WHERE `date` IN $dates", however this is not a good solution. So how can i pick dates 15 weeks back using pure MYSQL?

Answer (score 1):

```
select col1, col2 from blabla where date>=DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL 15 week)
```

Edit I assume you want only data for the same day of the week as the date is - try this:

```
select
    a.col1,
    a.col2
from
    blabla a
        join blabla b
            on weekday(a.date)=weekday(b.date)
where
    a.date>=date_sub(now(), interval 15 week)
    and b.date>=date_sub(now(), interval 15 week)
```

Comment: Sorry, but I wasnt clear enough I see now. I just want the individual dates (see table for expected result after query).
So using todays date, I want data for the days:
    2012-08-02, 
    2012-07-26, etc..

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select col1, col2 
from blabla 
where date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL 1 week) 
AND DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL 15 week) 
AND DAYOFWEEK(`date`) = 5
```

this will give you data from last week and 14 weeks back.

This (DATEPART(date,@dtDate) = 5) will return only thursdays.

Comment: I only want data every Thursday, not everything :)

Comment: You could as well use `DAYOFWEEK()`, especially since `DATEPART()` doesn't exist in MySQL. @EuclidesMulémbwè Have a look at my answer if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Use date field in mysql. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM foo 
WHERE `date` BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 week) AND DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 15 week)
AND DAYOFWEEK(`date`) = DAYOFWEEK(NOW());
```

More info [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek).